# On click event of picture box how to Open image in new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Fetching Images from folder and displaying them in picture box using following code

```
protected void image()
{
    string str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string path = str + "\\images\\";
    //Our target folder; change this to the folder to get the images from
    string GivenFolder = str + "\\images\\"; 
    //Initialize a new List of type Image as ImagesInFolder
    List<System.Drawing.Image> ImagesInFolder = new List<System.Drawing.Image>(); 

    // Initialize a new string of name JPEGImages for every string in the 
    // string array returned from the given folder as files 
    foreach (string JPEGImages in Directory.GetFiles(GivenFolder, "*.jpg")) 
    {
        //Add the Image gathered to the List collection
        ImagesInFolder.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(JPEGImages)); 
    }
    int x = 0; //Initialize X as int of value 0
    int y = 0; //Initialize Y as int of value 0
    // Initialize i as an int of value 0, continue if i is less than ImagesInFolder 
    // count. Increment i by 1 each time you continue
    for (int i = 0; i < ImagesInFolder.Count; i++) 
    {
        PictureBox I = new PictureBox(); //Initialize a new PictureBox of name I
        I.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); //Set the PictureBox location to x,y
        x += 50; //Sort horizontally; Increment x by 50
        //y += 50; //Sort vertically; Increment y by 50
        //Set the Image property of I to i in ImagesInFolder as index
        I.Image = ImagesInFolder[i]; 
        //Set the PictureBox Size property to 50,50
        I.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 80); 
        //Stretch the image; maximum width and height are 50,50
        I.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; 

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(I); //Add the PictureBox to the FlowLayoutPanel
    }
}
```

How can I write function so that I can open particular `picture box's image` in `click event` of that particular picture box ,in new `winform`,since I am creating picture box from code ,so I can't select event from propwerty window so please direct me how do I do this from code ,something like this

```
private void PictureboxClick_event()
{
FormtoOpen f=new FormtoOpen();
f.show();
//.....how that particular image will be displayed ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a common event handler when you create your `PictureBox's`

i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ImagesInFolder.Count; i++) 
{
    PictureBox I = new PictureBox(); //Initialize a new PictureBox of name I
    I.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); //Set the PictureBox location to x,y
    x += 50; //Sort horizontally; Increment x by 50
    //y += 50; //Sort vertically; Increment y by 50
    //Set the Image property of I to i in ImagesInFolder as index
    I.Image = ImagesInFolder[i]; 
    //Set the PictureBox Size property to 50,50
    I.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 80); 
    //Stretch the image; maximum width and height are 50,50
    I.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; 
    //Add the Event handler to the click event
    I.Click += pictureBox_Click;

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(I); //Add the PictureBox to the FlowLayoutPanel
}
```

In your click event you will find that the `sender` object is the `PictureBox` that originated the click event, so you can cast the sender object to a PictureBox and extract the Image out something like this.

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //This is supposing that you have created a custom constructor of your FormtoOpen that can take the Image
    //You could also create a Property to do the same thing.
    FormtoOpen f = new FormtoOpen(((PictureBox)sender).Image);
    f.Show();
}
```

---

As I said in the comment. You can create a custom Form Constructor something like this.

```
public partial class FormtoOpen : Form
{
    public FormtoOpen( Image img)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = img;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

or create a property/Method on FormtoOpen to do the same thing.

```
public void setPicture(Image img)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = img;
}
```

if you did this you would change `pictureBox_Click` to something like this.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormtoOpen form = new FormtoOpen();
    form.setPicture(((PictureBox)sender).Image);
    form.Show();
}
```

---

To expound on your question in the comments. Images have a `Tag` Property you can add the path to the Images tag then extract it in your second form. Change your `foreach` loop where you are filling your List to something like this

```
foreach (string JPEGImages in Directory.GetFiles(GivenFolder, "*.jpg"))
{
    //Add the Image gathered to the List collection
    Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(JPEGImages);
    img.Tag = JPEGImages;
    ImagesInFolder.Add(img);
}
```

It would then be available in your second form like this (*I am using the `setPicture` Method of my previous example as an example*)

```
public void setPicture(Image img)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = img;
    this.Text = img.Tag.ToString(); //The image's Tag property is an object so it needs to be converted to a string
}
```

Comment: can you please tell how can i pass the particular image's path in `FormtoOpen`

Comment: @Durga If you want to pass the path you will need to use the Tag property of the PictureBox. Just assign it with the value of the Image's path when you add the image to the PictureBox.

Comment: can you please show the above commented solution in code, for passing path

Comment: @Durga Not by PC, I will update this evening when I am at a computer again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40612/discussion-between-durga-and-mark-hall)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your event handler manually in your code behind something like:

```
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox(); //create picturebox
    pic.Click += pic_Click; // hook click event on picturebox


    void pic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here that opens the new form
    }
```